# Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in the pdfXFA example?

Tags: java, itext7, xfa

Trying the example found from here: https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfxfa

```
public static void main() {
        XFAFlattenerProperties flattenerProperties = new XFAFlattenerProperties()
                .setPdfVersion(XFAFlattenerProperties.PDF_1_7)
                .createXmpMetaData()
                .setTagged()
                .setMetaData(
                        new MetaData()
                            .setAuthor("iText Samples")
                            .setLanguage("EN")
                            .setSubject("Showing off our flattening skills")
                            .setTitle("Flattened XFA"));

        XFAFlattener xfaf = new XFAFlattener()
                .setFlattenerProperties(flattenerProperties);


        xfaf.flatten(new FileInputStream("xfaform.pdf"), new FileOutputStream("flat.pdf"));
}
```

and getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject`
when trying to do 
`XFAFlattener xfaf = new XFAFlattener();`

Not using Maven or POM. I have the following JARs in classpath:

- io-7.1.10.jar
- kernel-7.1.10.jar
- layout-7.1.10.jar
- itext-licensekey-3.0.6.jar
- pdfrender-1.0.0.jar
- pdfxfa-2.0.5.jar

Am I missing something?

Comment: You may have an library that is not up to date. I will suggest you to use `maven` for a better dependency management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `org.mozilla:rhino:1.7R4` dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mozilla/rhino/1.7R4

But as @Harry Coder mentioned, you should use Maven or Gradle or any other Maven-compatible build system that will download all the dependencies including transitive ones automatically for you